# How to compare the degree distributions of 2 different graphs

Tags: mathematical-statistics, data-visualization, igraph

I am new to statistics.I am trying to compare 2 networks. Can anyone pls help me to understand what the degree distribution of the 2 networks say. I mean the similarities or differences bet the 2 networks.

Degree distribution of original graph with 198 nodes & 2742 edges[image]
Degree distribution of a random graph with same nodes and vertices as above
[image]

Comment: You might have better luck with this question by posting it to the SOCNET listserv. Also, Matthew Jackson's Social Network Analysis MOOC w/ Coursera is an excellent intro to degree centrality, distribution, etc.

Answer (score 1):

First, I think it would be clearer to look at the degree distribution in density plots rather than cumulative plots like the ones you have.  A quantile quantile plot might also be useful.  You should also make the two axes align, as is, one goes from 0 to 40 and the other from 0 to 100, giving exactly the wrong impression of the data.

However, even with these graphs, let's look at, e.g. how many nodes have degree over 40. In your actual graph, it's about 20%. In the random graph it's close to 0. Next let's look at those with degree < 10. In the random network, it's almost none.  In your network, it's almost 20%.

So, your network has more nodes with very low degree and more with very high degree, leaving fewer with moderate degree.

It would be nice to know what your network is, but this is a fairly common pattern. Something like this pattern would happen with graphs of friendships or networks on Facebook or similar places.

Comment: the first graph seems to have a power law distribution but what about the random graph? Is it poisson. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: I can't really tell.